# Why is the temperature totally differentiable?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature

Suppose there is a function $T=T(p,V)$, called temperature, which is invertible in the whole space according to the pressure $p$ and the volume $V$.

Is it true that $T$ is a twice differentiable function of $p$ and $V$, and that furthermore $\frac{{{\partial }^{2}}T}{\partial p\partial V}=\frac{{{\partial }^{2}}T}{\partial V\partial p}$?

If yes, how can we prove it? If no, what additional criteria are necessary for such condition to hold?

Comment: In the special case of the ideal gas law, it flows from the ideal gas formula: p*V=n*R*T. Some key points are found at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_function#Differentiability_in_higher_dimensions For  ∂2T∂p∂V=∂2T∂V∂p to be true, I would think that you would need to show that p and V have effects that are either orthogonal or commutative within T(p,V). Since pressure and volume should have a functional relationship to each other similar to the ideal gas law even if the gas is not ideal, this should follow.

Comment: "I would think that you would need to show that p and V have effects that are either orthogonal or commutative within T(p,V). " Sorry, I don't clearly understand it.

Comment: A better explanation can be found her that references Swartz' theorem a.k.a. Clairaut's theorem, which provides that the order of partial differentiation is irrelevant if T(p, V) is continuous in both p and V (a weaker condition than I initially suggested). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_derivative#Higher_order_partial_derivatives The relationship between invertibility and differentiability is discussed at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_functions_and_differentiation and here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't still understand it. If T=T(V,p) is invertible according to V, then T would be continuous with respect to V?

Answer (score 2):

That constraint on the second derivatives with respect to $p$ and $V$ is a direct consequence of the temperature $T$ being a [state function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_function) of $p$ and $V$.
Physically this means that the values of $p$ and $V$ is all the information you need to compute the temperature for that state of the system.

This may seem an obvious condition to impose but it is not always verified for physical systems.
In fact, in many realistic scenarios increasing first the pression by an amount $\Delta p$ and *then* the volume by an amount $\Delta V$ you may obtain a different state (with a different temperature $T$), than the state you would have obtained by varying first the volume and then the pressure by the same amounts.

If on the other hand you want to describe a system for which the above is *not* true, that is, a system for which no matter the way you arrived to the pressure $p$ and volume $V$ you always have the same temperature, then this will impose a condition on the functional dependence of $T$ on $p$ and $V$, which assumes the form you mentioned:
$$ \frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial p\partial V} = \frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial V\partial p}. $$

There are many ways to see why $T$ being a state function implies the above.
Mathematically you can see it as an instance of [Schwarz's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives).
A more intuitive way to see it is to note that
$ \frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial V\partial p}(p,V) $
gives the amount of variation in $T$ if starting from $(p,V)$ you vary $p$ by a small amount $dp$ *and then* you vary $V$ by a small amount $dV$.
$ \frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial p\partial V}(p,V) $ is the same when varying first $V$ and then $p$, and if you want to impose that it does not matter the order with which you vary the parameters it immediately follows that these two quantities must be the same.

Comment: I would be curious why the temperature is a state function. This is the reasony why I thought of the symmetry of the Hessian. What is the MATHEMATICAL interpretation that temperature is a state function?

Comment: the physical intuition of it being a state function I think I outlined in the answer. I don't think there is any "mathematical interpretation": you impose the mathematical constraint of $T$ being a state function because this matches the physical situation you are trying to describe. If you are interested in more general situations (for example, study nonequilibrium transitions), than you will not want to impose that $T$ is a state function. In other words, it is not *necessary* that the second derivatives satisfy that equation, it is only true in some particular thermodynamic approximations.

Comment: I have read in a book that the state function "character" of the temperature implies from the zeroth law. Is this true? If yes, how?

Comment: Two more questions: Why the total differentiability implies from the state function "character"? Is this describable in an exact way?

Comment: What guarantees that U, V, n_1,n_2,...,n_K can describe the state of the system in equilibrium, where U is the internal energy, V is the volume, n_i is amount of the ith species in the system.

Comment: Is the differentiability included by the state function "character"?

Comment: A state function can flow naturally from any quantity that is energy conserving. For example, the kinetic energy of an object in motion a function of velocity without regard to the acceleration path used to attain that velocity. Given that temperature is ultimately a function of kinetic energy, it makes sense that it would be a state function.

Comment: @TobiR I'm not sure what you mean by "state function character"

Comment: What is the state function? I think that a state function is a function of state variables, which is invertible with respect to all their variables.  Is this true, or is the invertibility a consequence of an other definition of "state function"?

Comment: So, I perhaps understand why the temperature is invertible in p and V, but I don't know what involves that the state function is totally differentiable. If we use the concept in wiki (state function is a function defined for a system relating several state variables or state quantities that depends only on the current equilibrium state of the system), what guarantees that T is invertible? Invertibility implies that T is totally differentiable?